# Error en el paso 5.11 de la guía "Comenzando con Rails"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mvc, http, post

Estoy siguiendo una de las guías oficiales de Rails para hacer mi primer aplicación: [Comenzando con Rails](http://www.guiasrails.es/getting_started.html), que consta de 11 pasos en total. El objetivo de la misma es crear un blog.

### Contexto del error

He seguido todos los pasos al pie de la letra. Sin embargo en el paso *5.11 Actualizando Artículos* algo sale mal.

En el listado de artículos guardados, para cada uno hay dos enlaces: Uno para *Ver* y otro para *Editar* ese articulo. La opción *Editar* lo que hace es llevar a una pagina que permite cambiar tanto el titulo como el contenido, sin embargo ocurre el siguiente error al hacer clic en ese enlace:

> **ActionController::UnknownFormat in ArticulosController#edit**
>
> ArticulosController#edit is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot.

Sucede exactamente lo mismo tanto en Windows 7 Ultimate como en Linux Mint 17.3, *ambos de 64-bit*.

También he intentado quitar la definición de *update* en el controlador y borrar el archivo *edit.html.erb* solo para ver que ocurría, pero el error sigue siendo exactamente el mismo.

Versiones instaladas:

- RubyGems 2.6.11
- Ruby 2.4.0p0
- Rails 5.0.2

### Archivos involucrados

> app/controllers/articulos_controller.rb

```
class ArticulosController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @articulos = Articulo.all
    end

    def show
        @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @articulo = Articulo.new
    end

    def edit
        @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create

        @articulo = Articulo.new(articulo_params)

        if @articulo.save
            redirect_to @articulo
        else
            render 'new'
        end

    end

    def update

        @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:id])

        if @articulo.update(articulo_params)
            redirect_to @articulo
        else
            render 'edit'

        end

    end

    private def articulo_params
        params.require(:articulo).permit(:titular, :contenido)
    end

end
```

> app/views/articulos/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Artículos</h1>

<p>
  <%= link_to 'Principal', controller: 'bienvenido' %> |
  <%= link_to 'Crear', new_articulo_path %>  
</p>

<table>

  <tr>
    <th>Titular</th>
    <th>Contenido</th>
  </tr>

  <% @articulos.each do |articulo| %>

    <tr>
      <td><%= articulo.titular %></td>
      <td><%= articulo.contenido %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Ver', articulo_path(articulo) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Editar', edit_articulo_path(articulo) %></td>
    </tr>

  <% end %>

</table>
```

> app/views/articulos/edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Editando un artículo</h1>

<%= form_for :articulo, url: articulo_path(@articulo), method: :patch do |f|%>

  <% if @articulo.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@articulo.errors.count, "error") %> han impedido que el artículo sea grabado:
    </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @articulo.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :titular %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :titular %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :contenido %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :contenido %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Guardar Artículo' %>
  </p>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Volver', articulos_path %>
```

**Como puedo solucionar este error?**

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como contesta @AlterLagos, es un problema con template edit. El error te dice que

> ArticulosController#edit is missing a template for this request format and variant.

Lo que significa que está faltando el archivo `app/views/articulos/edit.html.erb`, revisa que el nombre de los archivo y la ubicación estén correctos.

Comment: En el nombre de archivo había un espacio luego de la extensión. Muchas gracias a los dos por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Ese error te lo tira porque no encuentra un template adecuado para mostrar la vista de editar.  Veo que en el ejemplo pusiste que el nombre del archivo es `app/views/articulos/edit.html.rb`, sin embargo debería ser `app/views/articulos/edit.html.erb`. En general los archivos de las vistas usan la extensión `.erb` (Embedded ruby).

Comment: Fue un descuido en la pregunta. En realidad los archivos efectivamente tienen esa extensión. Gracias por hacérmelo saber.